# knockoutjs nested templates value error

Tags: templates, nested, knockout.js

I am having an issue with the following code and it is wrecking my head.

The [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rayray/23L2Y/28/) throws the following exception when first run, yet it works when the Jquery UI modal is called.

Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: url is not defined;
Bindings value: value: url, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'

P.S Click on the folder name 'Folder1' to see the links, then click edit link to see the link modal edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The native templates don't protect as well against null as jQuery Templates did.  To protect against null, you can specify your template binding like:

```
<div id="details" data-bind="template: { name: 'editTmpl', if: selectedLink, data: selectedLink }, openDialog: selectedLink"> 
</div>
```

Comment: +1 to @RPNiemeyer s suggestion. I often find that I have to use the "if: foo" to first see if data exists before performing an operation. It would be nice if the data bindings would check it for us automatically :)

Comment: Thanks Rp Niemeyer that works, I have updated the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/23L2Y/29/